# ¿Cómo interpretar etiquetas html almacenadas en la BBDD como tal?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-7

En la BBDD tengo un campo llamado texto que guarda los datos con las etiquetas html ejemplo:

- < p >este es un párrafo de ejemplo</ p >*
  y yo quiero que en cuando lo recupero de la BBDD el html me reconozca las etiquetas.
  Quisiera que me lo mostrara así:

```
<p>
este es un párrafo de ejemplo
</p>
```

El problema es que cuando lo recupero me lo saca así tal cual el primer ejemplo.

Estoy usando Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo he solucionado, lo primero es instalar [BBCode](https://github.com/Genert/bbcode)

- composer require genert/bbcode
- El siguiente paso fue quitar el auto escape {{ $textoBBDD }} y utilice el unescaped {!! $textoBBDD !!} para poder visualizar el código HTML del texto.

Esta ha sido mi solución.